# Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I'm new to node.js. I'm writing a middleware but I'm stuck. It says

"Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined".

The same error occurs when I try for body and query. How can I fix this error?

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    //Kullanıcı bana bir token yollayacak
    //Farklı formatlarda bu token gelebilir
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.body.token || req.query.token
    // req.query.token => localhost:3000/api/movies/?token=asdasdsa olarak gelebilir
    if(token){
        jwt.verify(token, req.app.get('api_secret_key'), (err, decoded) => {
            if(err){
                res.json({
                    status: false,
                    message: 'Failed to authenticate token'
                })
            }
            else{
                // yapmış olan isteğin decode kısmına decoded'ı yazıyoruz
                req.decode = decoded
                next() // her şey yolunda herhangi bir route ile devam edebilirsin
            }

        })
    }else{
        res.json({
            status: false,
            message: 'No token provided'
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please change from `req.headers` to `req.header`

Comment: Can you confirm that the middleware is actually executing as expected?

Comment: @yarenska Are you facing this issue with `localhost` * URL's ?

Comment: How are you mount your plugin? Must be like const plugin = require('some-path'); server.use(plugin). I mean just pass - not run!